# Colocar iconos con texto CSS

Tags: html, css

Estaba haciendo un mini-proyecto personal, y al colocar un símbolo que tenga texto al lado sale de la siguiente forma:

```html
 <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="grid-item cuatro"> 
  <h1><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;">info</i> Hola</h1>
  <p><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;">play_arrow</i> Hola1<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;"> play_arrow</i> Hola2 <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i> Hola3 </p>
  <p><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;">play_arrow</i>Hola4<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;">play_arrow</i> Hola 5 </p>
  <p><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;">play_arrow</i>Hola6<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;">play_arrow</i>Hola 7</p>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

¿Cómo se podría conseguir alinear el texto con la etiqueta `<i>`?

He estado buscando, pero solo encontraba cómo alinear con imágenes, pero al no ser una imagen, no funcionaba.

Gracias por su atención

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de una manera limpia con `display: flex`, a través de la propiedad `align-items: center`. Esto provoca que todo el contenido del `<p>` (tanto el texto como el icono) se posicionen en el centro de todo el espacio del que dispongan verticalmente.

```css
.cuatro p, .cuatro h1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="grid-item cuatro"> 
  <h1><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;">info</i> Hola</h1>
  <p><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;">play_arrow</i> Hola1<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;"> play_arrow</i> Hola2 <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue">play_arrow</i> Hola3 </p>
  <p><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;">play_arrow</i>Hola4<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;">play_arrow</i> Hola 5 </p>
  <p><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;">play_arrow</i>Hola6<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px; color: DarkSlateBlue;">play_arrow</i>Hola 7</p>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```